# javascript operators using AND and OR in conditional statements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a message if only the conditional statements meet a certain requirement but with what I'm getting it fails me. Currently, the script is like this

```
 if ((err.status === 401 && !request.url.includes("users") || !request.url.includes("friends")) ) {
      console.log('hello')

    }
```

What I want to achieve is when the status is `401` and the URL doesn't include either `users` or `friends` the `console` should log `hello` but it fails to work

when I change the code to this

```
   if ((err.status === 401 && !request.url.includes("users")) ) {
          console.log('hello')

        }
```

or this

```
 if ((err.status === 401 && !request.url.includes("friends")) ) {
          console.log('hello')

        }
```

it works, but I want it to check for both conditions

Comment: Just change `||` to `&&` if you need to check that url not included 'users' AND not included 'friends'

Comment: `if(err.status==401 && !(request.url.includes("users") || request.url.includes("friends")))`

Comment: a AND (not (b OR c)) === a AND (not b) AND (not c) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap the `||` for a `&&`

```
if (err.status === 401 && !request.url.includes("users") && !request.url.includes("friends")) {
    console.log('hello')
}
```

If you think it through in your head it would sound like the following.

1. The `status` has to be `401`
2. **AND** the `url` should **NOT** include `users`
3. **AND** the `url` should **NOT** include `friends`

If you want to code it like you wrote it:

1. The `status` has to be `401`
2. **AND** The `url` should **NOT** include `users` **OR** `friends`

You could still do that, but just a little different:

```
if (err.status === 401 && !(request.url.includes("users") || request.url.includes("friends"))) {
    console.log('hello')
}
```

Both these codes mean exactly the same, just write it how you prefer it more. But always write it like it flows in your head. Just type out what you think :)

Answer (score 1):

For string validations I suggest you to use **Regular Expressions** (It can allow more complex validations)

```js
if(error.status === 401 && !/users|friends/.test(request.url)){
  console.log("hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that is parallel to the wording:

```
if(err.status==401 && !(request.url.includes("users") || request.url.includes("friends")))
```

Visually:

```
if
(
  err.status==401
  &&
  !
    (
      request.url.includes("users")
      ||
      request.url.includes("friends")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is almost ok, just some issue with brackets **()**.

the format is  :

```
if( cond1 && !(  cond2 || cond3  ) ) {
 ----- your logic ------
}
```

so your example should be like :

```
if ( err.status === 401 && !( request.url.includes("users") || request.url.includes("friends") ) )  {
            console.log('hello')
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I am going to change the code. thanks for pointing out the mistake.